# Clang static analysis under VisualStudio2012

Tags: c, visual-studio-2012, clang

how to invoke static analysis in VisualStudio 2012? I have installed newest Clang and VisualStudioPlugin form http://llvm.org/builds/ and added --analyze in 'Additional Options' ( Properties->Config Properties->C/C++->Command Line). When I try to compile I get

```
1>clang-cl.exe : error : unknown argument: '--analyze'
```